# error in daemonThread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyThread2 implements Runnable {

    private Thread t;
    private File f;

    public MyThread2(File f) {
        t=new Thread(this,"MyThread2");
        if(!t.isDaemon())
            t.setDaemon(true);
        this.f=f;
        t.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        byte b[];
        try(FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f,true)){
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                String s="Daemon thread ";
                b=s.getBytes();
                fos.write(b);

                Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("DEAMON THREAD ALIVE??"+t.isAlive());
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch(IOException e){
        }
    }
}    


class DemoThread2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        File f=new File("E:\\java rev\\Java\\thread\\my notes\\thread.txt");

        if(!f.exists())
            f.createNewFile();
        MyThread2 t=new MyThread2(f);
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("The Main Thread Is Exiting");



    }
}
```

Here The Daemon Thread Is Active even after The Jvm is exiting after the User's main thread has exited and accordingly it should be able to write to the file!!but only once its writing!!

Comment: but i have done it u can see!!

Comment: seems like the daemon thread is lingering for a couple of seconds after the `main()` ends and before the JVM actually shuts down.. that's why its writing only once. This might just be a matter of *delay* in shutting down the JVM.

Comment: I tried your code, and I can't reproduce the problem (JDK 1.7.0_55, Windows).

Comment: i didn't get U!!and that what i want that it(daemon) will exist even after the main thread exists!!

Comment: I don't see what's surprising here - Since it's a daemon thread, it won't keep the JVM alive, so it only manages to write to the file once (while the main thread is sleeping). After the main thread finishes the JVM shuts down since no non-daemon threads are left.

Comment: If you want `MyThread2` to keep running even after the main thread finishes, then *don't* make it a daemon thread.

Comment: *what i want that it(daemon) will exist even after the main thread exists!* - Thats not possible. The JVM shuts down when all threads running in it are *daemon* threads.

Comment: If you want the thread to keep running even after all the other threads (i.e. the main thread, here) have finished, then the thread should NOT be a daemon thread. A daemon thread is precisely a thread that does NOT prevent the JVM to exit even if it's still running. Don't call setDaemon(true).

Comment: ##JB Nizet u should try  jdk 1.7 as try-with resource may getting an error!!

Comment: You could change the *priority* of the thread and make it (suggest the JVM) run with a lower priority.  Although there is no guarantee that this would actually work.

Comment: # JB Nizet a simple question??does daemon thread really works even after the jvm exits???

Comment: All Java threads run inside the JVM. When the JVM shuts down, all the Java threads stop existing. By marking a thread as a *daemon thread*, you tell the JVM that it's OK to shut down that thread even though it is not finished yet, if the program is otherwise done (all non-daemon threads are finished).